# Dynamic Count of items +/- 15% per row value

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table with a column of building sizes named "SQFT".  I trying to find the number of buildings that are within 15% +/- of each rows "SQFT" value.
I have tried case, count with filter and window functions but none would give me the results I'm looking for, at least not in the way I was using them.

Below is what I'd like as a final result.

```
ID   -15%    SQFT    +15%    COUNT
1    85      100     115     2
2    94      110     127     3
3    102     120     138     3
4    111     130     150     4
5    119     140     161     5
6    128     150     173     5
7    136     160     184     5
8    145     170     196     5
9    153     180     207     5
10   162     190     219     5
11   170     200     230     7
12   179     210     242     7
13   187     220     253     7
14   196     230     265     6
15   204     240     276     5
16   213     250     288     4
```

This is the code so far:

```
WITH base AS (
   SELECT "Unique ID" as id, "Sqft Total" AS "SQFT", "Sqft Total" * (1-.15) as low, "Sqft Total" * (1+.15) as high
   FROM   "_KEY_TABLE"
   )
SELECT  
    id,
    round(low::numeric,0) as "-15%",
    sqft,
    round(high::numeric,0) as "+15%",
    count(*) over(partition by "SQFT" between low and high) as "COUNT"
    -- case when "SQFT" between low and high is true then 1 end, 
    -- count(*) filter (where "SQFT" between low and high) as counter_filtered,
FROM   base b
group by b."SQFT", id, low, high
```

Comment: Provide the sample data and desired result, desired result without sample data is useless.

Comment: Evan, thank you for your reply. Yes, I could have been more clear. The desired result is the "COUNT" column. The other columns are the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but I imagine it's something like this. Here we use a `INNER JOIN` and check the right table for the range.

```
-- sample data
WITH t(x) AS (SELECT generate_series(1,10))

SELECT t1.x,
  t1.x*0.85 AS lower, -- just so you can see the lower
  t1.x*1.15 AS upper, -- just so you can see the upper
  count(*)
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2
  ON t2.x BETWEEN t1.x*0.85 AND t1.x*1.15  -- JOY
GROUP BY t1.x
ORDER BY t1.x;
```

Output,

```
 x  | lower | upper | count 
----+-------+-------+-------
  1 |  0.85 |  1.15 |     1
  2 |  1.70 |  2.30 |     1
  3 |  2.55 |  3.45 |     1
  4 |  3.40 |  4.60 |     1
  5 |  4.25 |  5.75 |     1
  6 |  5.10 |  6.90 |     1
  7 |  5.95 |  8.05 |     3
  8 |  6.80 |  9.20 |     3
  9 |  7.65 | 10.35 |     3
 10 |  8.50 | 11.50 |     2
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you Evan and McNets, both of your solutions worked perfectly. Alas, I can only choose one correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> create table buildings (Id int, Sqft int);
>
> insert into buildings values
> (1,  100), (2,  110), (3,  120), (4,  130), (5,  140), (6,  150), (7,  160), (8,  170), 
> (9,  180), (10, 190), (11, 200), (12, 210), (13, 220), (14, 230), (15, 240), (16, 250);
> ```

> ```
> select Id, 
>        Sqft * (1 - .15) as low,
>        Sqft,
>        Sqft * (1 + .15) as high,
>        (select count(*) 
>         from   buildings t2
>         where  t2.Sqft between (t.Sqft * (1 - .15)) and  (t.Sqft * (1 + .15))) as "count"
> from   buildings t
> ```
>
> ```
> id |    low | sqft |   high | count
> -: | -----: | ---: | -----: | ----:
>  1 |  85.00 |  100 | 115.00 |     2
>  2 |  93.50 |  110 | 126.50 |     3
>  3 | 102.00 |  120 | 138.00 |     3
>  4 | 110.50 |  130 | 149.50 |     3
>  5 | 119.00 |  140 | 161.00 |     5
>  6 | 127.50 |  150 | 172.50 |     5
>  7 | 136.00 |  160 | 184.00 |     5
>  8 | 144.50 |  170 | 195.50 |     5
>  9 | 153.00 |  180 | 207.00 |     5
> 10 | 161.50 |  190 | 218.50 |     5
> 11 | 170.00 |  200 | 230.00 |     7
> 12 | 178.50 |  210 | 241.50 |     7
> 13 | 187.00 |  220 | 253.00 |     7
> 14 | 195.50 |  230 | 264.50 |     6
> 15 | 204.00 |  240 | 276.00 |     5
> 16 | 212.50 |  250 | 287.50 |     4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2eca80be48f9375d0ccc24a8ebe8d87e)*